# Upgrade ActiveMQ 5.12.1 to 5.14.1

Tags: activemq-classic

I've currently got ActiveMQ 5.12.1 running and want to upgrade to ActiveMQ 5.14.1. I can't seem to find any documentation on upgrading from one version to another. Is it as simple as copying the files over? I don't want to lose any of my queues or subscribers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important data is in the persistence-store, i.e. typically KahaDB.

You can simply install the new ActiveMQ version and copy the store (or simply point it out if it's on a shared disk or whatnot) and all messages should remain.

Although the configuration is probably just fine to copy, I would make it a habit to look through the release notes of new features and improvements and see if there is something you can use. This is even more important if you use advanced AMQ features such as network of brokers or newer features where there are more updates, such as AMQP, MQTT and WebSockets.

If there is some major thing that needs attention from one version to another, there will be a note in the release-notes.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I copied the KahaDB folder into the 5.14.1 folder and it all worked. Appreciate the assist.

Comment: HI, Can you please see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40671966/activemq-web-console-not-starting-up-after-upgrade.