# ActiveMQ web Console not starting up after upgrade

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I am Upgrading ActiveMQ 5.11.1 to 5.14.1. When start the ActiveMQ, it shows that it is started in the console as below.

```
activemq console


Refreshing org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@2b0de40c: startup date [Fri Nov 18 07:43:43 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
 INFO | Using Persistence Adapter: KahaDBPersistenceAdapter[/home/rajesh/workspace/portalTrunk/testArea/jms_store]
 INFO | KahaDB is version 6
 INFO | JMX consoles can connect to service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:43026/jmxrmi
 INFO | Recovering from the journal @1:2525
 INFO | Recovery replayed 5 operations from the journal in 0.012 seconds.
 INFO | PListStore:[/home/rajesh/workspace/portalTrunk/testArea/activemq/data/172.17.40.17/tmp_storage] started
 INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.14.1 (172.17.40.17, ID:172.17.40.17-46207-1479435224633-0:1) is starting
 INFO | Listening for connections at: tcp://172.17.40.17:43011
 INFO | Connector openwire started
 INFO | Listening for connections at: stomp://172.17.40.17:43012
 INFO | Connector stomp started
 INFO | Listening for connections at: ssl://172.17.40.17:43071
 INFO | Connector ssl started
 INFO | Establishing network connection from vm://172.17.40.17?create=false&async=false to ssl://localhost:43071
 INFO | Connector vm://172.17.40.17 started
 INFO | Network Connector DiscoveryNetworkConnector:host1 and host2:BrokerService[172.17.40.17] started
 INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.14.1 (172.17.40.17, ID:172.17.40.17-46207-1479435224633-0:1) started
 INFO | For help or more information please see: http://activemq.apache.org
 INFO | 172.17.40.17 Shutting down host1 and host2
 WARN | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:44630 failed: java.io.EOFException
 INFO | 172.17.40.17 bridge to Unknown stopped
 INFO | Connector vm://172.17.40.17 stopped
 INFO | ActiveMQ WebConsole available at http://localhost:43021/
 INFO | ActiveMQ Jolokia REST API available at http://localhost:43021/api/jolokia/
 INFO | Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
 INFO | jolokia-agent: Using policy access restrictor classpath:/jolokia-access.xml
```

But When open the URL http://localhost:43021 I am getting site can not be reached.

I don't know where i am making mistake. When i rollback to the version 5.11.1 everything works great.

Can nay one help me where i am making mistake.

Here my Jetty.xml changes

```
<bean id="jettyPort" class="org.apache.activemq.web.WebConsolePort" init-method="start">
       <!--   the default port number for the web console -->
    <property name="host" value="localhost"/>
    <property name="port" value="${JMS_ADMIN_PORT}"/>
</bean>

 <bean id="Server" depends-on="jettyPort" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server" init-method="start"
    destroy-method="stop">
    <property name="handler">
        <bean id="handlers" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection">
            <property name="handlers">
                <list>
                    <ref bean="contexts" />
                    <ref bean="securityHandler" />
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>

</bean>

<bean id="invokeConnectors" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="Server" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="setConnectors" />
    <property name="arguments">
    <list>
        <bean id="Connector" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
            <constructor-arg ref="Server" />
                <!-- see the jettyPort bean -->
               <property name="host" value="localhost" />
               <property name="port" value="${JMS_ADMIN_PORT}" />
           </bean>
            <!--
                Enable this connector if you wish to use https with web console
            -->
            <bean id="SecureConnector" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
                <constructor-arg ref="Server" />
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean id="handlers" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory">

                         <property name="keyStorePath" value="file:${JMS_KEY_STORE}" />
                        <property name="keyStorePassword" value="${JMS_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD}" />
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                <property name="port" value="${JMS_ADMIN_PORT}" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="configureJetty" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="staticMethod" value="org.apache.activemq.web.config.JspConfigurer.configureJetty" />
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <ref bean="Server" />
            <ref bean="secHandlerCollection" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="invokeStart" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean" 
    depends-on="configureJetty, invokeConnectors">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="Server" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="start" />      
</bean>
```

Comment: The activeMq console shows it as running but i can not open the URL of web console. Can you guys help me?

Comment: Why are you using the same port for HTTP and HTTPS? Seems odd.

Comment: I do need only https port. So, where should i change or delete the JMS_ADMIN_PORT.

Comment: Yes, i just sloved this by using different ports